# Prove that $\frac{a}{2a+b^2}+\frac{b}{2b+c^2}+\frac{c}{2c+a^2}\le1$ where $ab+bc+ca=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $ab+bc+ca=3$. Prove that$$\frac{a}{2a+b^2}+\frac{b}{2b+c^2}+\frac{c}{2c+a^2}\le1$$

Source from: AwesomeMath summer program 2022, Algebra 3.5, test2.

I once tried to make it homogeneous via $\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}$ but this only makes it much more complicated
Then I made some progress using Chebyshev's inequality as following:

Switching it into greater or equal by$$\frac{a}{2a+b^2}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{b^2}{2(2a+b^2)}$$
And thus$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b^2}{2a+b^2}=\sum_{cyc}(a+b+c)(\frac{b}{a+b+c}\cdot\frac{b}{2a+b^2})\ge1\dots\boxed{0}$$
Then I use weighted Chebyshev's Inequality, seeing$\frac{a}{a+b+c},\frac{b}{a+b+c},\frac{c}{a+b+c}$ as weights
$$(\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{a+b+c})(\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{a+b+c}\cdot\frac{1}{2a+b^2}\cdot b)\ge(\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{a+b+c}\cdot\frac{1}{2a+b^2})(\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{a+b+c}\cdot b)\dots\boxed{1}$$
And by Chebyshev's inequality$$3(\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{a+b+c}\cdot\frac{1}{2a+b^2})\ge(\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{a+b+c})(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b^2})=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b^2}\dots\boxed{2}$$
Combing $\boxed{1}$ and $\boxed{2}$
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b^2}{2a+b^2}\ge\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{a+b+c}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{2a+b^2}$$
In order to reach $\boxed{0}$, the only thing left to be proved is that
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)(\frac{1}{2a+b^2}+\frac{1}{2b+c^2}+\frac{1}{2c+a^2})\ge3$$
Here is where I stuck, though I have no idea how to apply the criteria $ab+bc+ca=3$ for further process.

Comment: This problem has come up _a lot_ on Art of Problem Solving.  Here's the Approach0 search:  https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7B2a%2Bb%5E2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7B2b%2Bc%5E2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7B2c%2Ba%5E2%7D%5Cle1%24&p=1

Answer (score 1):

A full expanding gives $$\sum_{cyc}a^3c^2+a^2b^2c^2\geq4abc.$$
Let $ab=z$, $ac=y$ and $bc=x$.

Thus, $x+y+z=3$, $a=\sqrt{\frac{yz}{x}},$ $b=\sqrt{\frac{xz}{y}}$, $c=\sqrt{\frac{xy}{z}}$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{y^3z^3}{x^3}}\frac{xy}{z}+xyz\geq4\sqrt{xyz}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2}{x}+\sqrt{xyz}\geq4.$$
Now, let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2,$ where $v>0$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, $u=1$, $u\geq v$ and by C-S, AM-GM, Jensen for $f(t)=t^{\frac{3}{2}}$,Schur and AM-GM again  we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^2}{x}+\sqrt{xyz}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{y^3}{xy}+\sqrt{xyz}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{x^3}\right)^2}{xy+xz+yz}+xyz=\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3+6\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{x^3y^3}}{3}}{3v^2}+w^3\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{x^3+y^3+z^3+6\left(\frac{xy+xz+yz}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3v^2}+w^3=\frac{27u^3-27uv^2+3w^3+6v^3}{3v^2}+\frac{w^3}{u^2}=$$
$$=\frac{9u^3-9uv^2+2v^3+w^3}{v^2}+\frac{w^3}{u^2}\geq\frac{9u^3-9uv^2+2v^3+4uv^2-3u^3}{v^2}+\frac{4uv^2-3u^3}{u^2}=$$
$$=4+\frac{6u^3-5uv^2+2v^3}{v^2}+\frac{4v^2-3u^2}{u}-4=4+\frac{2(3u^4-6u^2v^2+uv^3+2v^4)}{uv^2}\geq$$
$$\geq4+\frac{2\left(6\sqrt[6]{u^{13}v^{11}}-6u^2v^2\right)}{uv^2}\geq4+\frac{2\left(6\sqrt[6]{u^{12}v^{12}}-6u^2v^2\right)}{uv^2}=4.$$

Comment: Your idea is very nice. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Supplement to Michael Rozenberg's nice proof**:

It suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, z> 0$ with $x + y + z = 3$,
$$\frac{x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + 6\left(\frac{xy + yz + zx}{3}\right)^{3/2}}{xy + yz + zx} + xyz \ge 4$$
or
$$\frac{x^3 + y^3 + z^3}{xy + yz + zx} + 2\sqrt{\frac{xy + yz + zx}{3}} + xyz \ge 4.$$

By AM-GM, we have
$\sqrt u = \frac{2u}{2\sqrt u} \ge \frac{2u}{1 + u}$ for all $u > 0$. We have
$$\sqrt{\frac{xy + yz + zx}{3}}
\ge \frac{2\cdot \frac{xy + yz + zx}{3}}{1 + \frac{xy + yz + zx}{3}} = \frac{2(xy + yz + zx)}{3 + xy + yz + zx}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{x^3 + y^3 + z^3}{xy + yz + zx} + 2\cdot \frac{2(xy + yz + zx)}{3 + xy + yz + zx} + xyz \ge 4. \tag{1}$$

Let $p = x + y + z = 3, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$.
(1) is written as
$$\frac{27 - 9q + 3r}{q} + \frac{4q}{3 + q} + r \ge 4.$$

Using Schur $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} x(x-y)(x-z) \ge 0$ which is written as $p^3 - 4pq + 9r \ge 0$, we have
$$r \ge \frac{4pq - p^3}{9} = \frac{12 q - 27}{9}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{27 - 9q + 3\cdot \frac{12 q - 27}{9}}{q} + \frac{4q}{3 + q} + \frac{12 q - 27}{9} \ge 4$$
or
$$\frac{2(3-q)(27-2q^2)}{3q(3+q)} \ge 0$$
which is true using $0 \le q \le p^2/3 = 3$.

We are done.